# Query from Postgres to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migration

I have this query in PostgreSQL and I am not familiar with PostgreSQL. I need to convert it to SQL Server.

```
SELECT (applicant_majors.*)::applicant_majors 
FROM applicant_majors 
WHERE applicant_majors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_1).id 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

This is the whole query

```
           FROM (SELECT college_attendeds,
                    colleges,
                    applicant_degree_1,
                    applicant_degree_2,
                    (SELECT (applicant_majors.*)::applicant_majors FROM applicant_majors WHERE applicant_majors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_1).id ORDER BY id           LIMIT 1         ) AS applicant_degree_1_applicant_major_1,
                    (SELECT (applicant_majors.*)::applicant_majors FROM applicant_majors WHERE applicant_majors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_1).id ORDER BY id           LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS applicant_degree_1_applicant_major_2,
                    (SELECT (applicant_minors.*)::applicant_minors FROM applicant_minors WHERE applicant_minors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_1).id ORDER BY minor_number LIMIT 1         ) AS applicant_degree_1_applicant_minor_1,
                    (SELECT (applicant_minors.*)::applicant_minors FROM applicant_minors WHERE applicant_minors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_1).id ORDER BY minor_number LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS applicant_degree_1_applicant_minor_2,
                    (SELECT (applicant_majors.*)::applicant_majors FROM applicant_majors WHERE applicant_majors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_2).id ORDER BY id           LIMIT 1         ) AS applicant_degree_2_applicant_major_1,
                    (SELECT (applicant_majors.*)::applicant_majors FROM applicant_majors WHERE applicant_majors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_2).id ORDER BY id           LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS applicant_degree_2_applicant_major_2,
                    (SELECT (applicant_minors.*)::applicant_minors FROM applicant_minors WHERE applicant_minors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_2).id ORDER BY minor_number LIMIT 1         ) AS applicant_degree_2_applicant_minor_1,
                    (SELECT (applicant_minors.*)::applicant_minors FROM applicant_minors WHERE applicant_minors.applicant_degree_id = (applicant_degree_2).id ORDER BY minor_number LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS applicant_degree_2_applicant_minor_2
               FROM (SELECT (college_attendeds.*)::college_attendeds AS college_attendeds,(colleges.*)::college_bases AS colleges,
                            (SELECT (applicant_degrees.*)::applicant_degrees FROM applicant_degrees WHERE applicant_degrees.college_attended_id = college_attendeds.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1         ) AS applicant_degree_1,
                            (SELECT (applicant_degrees.*)::applicant_degrees FROM applicant_degrees WHERE applicant_degrees.college_attended_id = college_attendeds.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS applicant_degree_2
                       FROM college_attendeds
            LEFT OUTER JOIN college_bases AS colleges ON (college_attendeds).college_id = colleges.id AND colleges.type = 'College') AS applicant_degree_data) AS college_attended_data
LEFT OUTER JOIN degree_bases AS applicant_degree_1_degree ON (applicant_degree_1).degree_id = applicant_degree_1_degree.id AND applicant_degree_1_degree.type IN ('Degree', 'PtDegree')
  LEFT OUTER JOIN degree_bases AS applicant_degree_2_degree ON (applicant_degree_2).degree_id = applicant_degree_2_degree.id AND applicant_degree_2_degree.type IN ('Degree', 'PtDegree');
```

Comment: What is `applicant_degree_1`?

Comment: The cast `(applicant_majors.*)::applicant_majors` is pretty much useless and a complicated way of writing `*`. The `(applicant_degree_1).id` looks pretty strange. That would only be valid if `applicant_degree_1` was a composite type - which is not available in SQL Server.

Comment: update the question with the whole query to include applicant_degree_1

Comment: That doesn't look like a whole query. No query starts with a `FROM`.

Comment: i didn't add the selected fields .

Answer (score 0):

`applicant_degree_1` its a subquery that contains:

```
SELECT (applicant_degrees.*)::applicant_degrees FROM applicant_degrees     
WHERE applicant_degrees.college_attended_id = college_attendeds.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

> The query above try to get the greatest id from `applicant_degrees` for each `college_attended_id`.

Then, I beleive your query can run on MSSQL like this:

```
SELECT applicant_majors.*
FROM applicant_majors 
WHERE applicant_majors.applicant_degree_id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM applicant_degrees 
    WHERE applicant_degrees.college_attended_id = college_attendeds.id
)
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

> **Notice** that I changed the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for a `MAX` aggregate function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 works in SQL server

Comment: what about this line 
SELECT (college_attendeds.*)::college_attendeds AS college_attendeds,
                                (colleges.*)::college_bases AS colleges,
how can we As with select * ?

Comment: yes @sebeid, it works. I change the `LIMIT|OFFSET` by `MAX()` because makes more sense using the function to get the max value.